# How to configure abandon timeout on Apache Directory API Ldap Pool

Tags: java, api, ldap, connection-pooling, apache-directory

I am writing an app with Apache Directory API (1.0.0-M33) to access LDAP directory. The app use the LdapConnectionPool object to handle these connections. Even the best practice is to borrow objects and return them to the pool I don't trust programmers so I'd like to abandon unused connections when the pool is exhausted.

The pool is based on GenericObjectPool from Apache-Commons-Pool. Abandoned configuration is only available since version 2.0 but the LDAP API 1.0.0-M33 uses common-pool 1.6.

I tried different configurations playing with Idle and Evict times and values but I cannot get the expected behaviour.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001801/how-to-return-objects-to-the-pool-by-timeout-using-apache-commons-pool) that looks similar but It doesn't fix the issue. Does anyone know how to implement this behaviour with Apache LDAP API 1.0.0-M33 ?